# What is the difference between sequence-to-sequence and sequence-to-one regression in LSTM networks?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, lstm

[Matlab documents two ways to use LSTM networks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/long-short-term-memory-networks.html) for regression:

[image: Schematic]

- **sequence-to-sequence**: The output of the LSTM layer is a *sequence*, fed into a fully connected layer. `lstmLayer(N, 'OutputMode', 'sequence'`).
- **sequence-to-one**: The output of the LSTM layer is the *last element of the sequence*, fed into a fully connected layer. `lstmLayer(N, 'OutputMode', 'last'`).

What is the difference between the two in context of time series prediction? When should one be used over the other?

---

*Notes*: [An example for time-series prediction](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/examples/time-series-forecasting-using-deep-learning.html) uses sequence-to-sequence architecture. If all you need is to predict the next time step, why output a whole sequence? I did not see any examples of sequence-to-one regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sequence-to-sequence**: The output is the hidden state of the LSTM cell at each time step in the input sequence. We want the state of the LSTM as it consumes each point in the sequence and considers its previous state. For example when you are differentiating a time series, you want the "gradient" at each point in the sequence:

```
x4  x3  x2  x1
           [LSTM]
            (h1)

    x4  x3   x2    x1
           [LSTM]
             (h2)  (h1)

        x4   x3     x2    x1
           [LSTM]
             (h3)  (h2)  (h1)
```

The LSTM is basically *translating* the input sequence into an output sequence. The output would be `(h4) (h3)  (h2)  (h1)`.

**sequence-to-one**: In this case, it is assumed that all we want is the state of the LSTM after consuming the whole sequence. For example, when you are integrating a time-series, you want the end result after integrating the whole sequence:

```
             x4     x3    x2    x1
           [LSTM]
             (h4)  (h3)  (h2)   (h1)
```

So the output would just be `(h4)`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to predict `i` events after the given sequence, you can use seq-to-seq (the second sequence with the size of `i`) and when you want to predict the next step of the input sequence, you can using `seq-to-one` to predict the next step of the input sequence.